# "API Key not valid" error when reading tasks from Google calendar

Tags: winforms, google-api

In my Winform app, I am using Google API to read calendar and contact data.  Whenever I read tasks, I got the "API Key not valid. Please pass a valid API KEY [400]" error.  I was able to read and write calendar event data using the same API token.  The scopes in the OAuth request included "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks ".  The OAuth user autherization screen also included "Create, edit, organize, and delete all your tasks".

Basically the error I got didn't make sense since I was able to use the same API key (token) to read other Google data but somehow failed with tasks.  Moreover, I get the same error if I read a large set of Calendar event data in a loop.  The error would happen somewhere between 10-30 records.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

I started to get the same error a few days ago.
Still no solution (

Comment: Can you tell me more about your situation?  I would like to know if it's exactly the same.  Thank you.

Comment: Found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527656/google-calendar-api-error-api-key-not-valid-please-pass-a-valid-api-key